# Slow query log - Row_send record count differs with actual records

Tags: mysql, mariadb, mysql-slow-query-log

Recently in my application which uses MariaDB 10.6, I am facing some weird issues where the same query took more than the expected time and consumes more IO at random times.

Enabled slow query to trace the same where we see a query stuck more than 9min and consumes more IO.

```
# Time: 230119 15:25:02
# User@Host: user[user] @  [192.*.*.*]
# Thread_id: 125616  Schema: DB  QC_hit: No
# Query_time: 567.099806  Lock_time: 0.000500  Rows_sent: 48  Rows_examined: 10859204
# Rows_affected: 0  Bytes_sent: 0
SET timestamp=1674152702;
select column1,column2....columnN where column1=v1 and column2=v2 and column3=v3 and column4=v4 and column5=v5;
```

On seeing the DB processlist, more no of query are in state "Waiting for table metadata lock" and end up in bigger issues.

```
| 106804 | userx | IP  | DB | Query       |   4239 | Sending data                                                  | Q1 |    0.000 |
| 106838 | userx | IP  | DB | Query       |   1980 | Waiting for table metadata lock                               | Q2 |    0.000 |
| 107066 | userx | IP  | DB | Sleep       |      0 |                                                               | NULL                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                             |    0.000 |
| 107196 | userx | IP  | DB | Sleep       |      1 |                                                               | NULL                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                             |    0.000 |
| 107223 | userx | IP  | DB | Query       |   4363 | Sending data                                                  | Q3 |    0.000 |
| 107277 | userx | IP  | DB | Query       |   3221 | Sending data                                                  | Q4 |    0.000 |
| 107299 | userx | IP  | DB | Sleep       |     26 |                                                               | NULL                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                             |    0.000 |
| 107324 | userx | IP  | DB | Sleep       |     54 |                                                               | NULL                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                             |    0.000 |
| 107355 | userx | IP  | DB | Sleep       |      0 |                                                               | NULL                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                             |    0.000 |
| 107357 | userx | IP  | DB | Sleep       |      1 |                                                               | NULL                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                             |    0.000 |
| 107417 | userx | IP  | DB | Query       |   1969 | Waiting for table metadata lock                               |  |    0.000 |
| 107462 | userx | IP  | DB | Sleep       |     55 |                                                               | NULL                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                             |    0.000 |
| 107489 | userx | IP  | DB | Query       |   1979 | Waiting for table metadata lock                               | Q5 |    0.000 |
| 107492 | userx | IP  | DB | Sleep       |     25 |                                                               | NULL                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                             |    0.000 |
| 107519 | userx | IP  | DB | Query       |   1981 | Waiting for table metadata lock                               | Q6 |    0.000 |
```

Currently, the manual killing of the suspected query using **KILL query** cmd unblocks the other query to complete, and via MariaDB property, we can use max_statement_time to terminate the long-running query.

But Is there a way to check what was killed by the max_statement_time? Unable to find any traces in `error.log`.

The actual query should return around 1765 records while the slow query reports row_sent as 48.

1. Is it a problem with scanning the table or record fetched got stuck after some time?
2. Or Am I misinterpreting the slow query output Row_send record count

```
127.0.0.1:3307> select column1,column2....columnN where column1=v1 and column2=v2 and column3=v3 and column4=v4 and column5=v5;

+----------+
| count(*) |
+----------+
|     1756 |
+----------+
1 row in set (0.006 sec)
```

---EDITED---
Missed adding column 5 added now in the query.
The table is indexed and let me explain the statement.

```
127.0.0.1:3307> explain extended select..... from Tablename where column1=v1 and column2=v2 and column3=v3 and column4=v4 and column5=v5;

+------+-------------+-------+------+---------------+---------+---------+-------------------------------+------+----------+-------+
| id   | select_type | table | type | possible_keys | key     | key_len | ref                           | rows | filtered | Extra |
+------+-------------+-------+------+---------------+---------+---------+-------------------------------+------+----------+-------+
|    1 | SIMPLE      | s     | ref  | PRIMARY       | PRIMARY | 7       | const,const,const,const,const | 73  |   100.00 |       |
+------+-------------+-------+------+---------------+---------+---------+-------------------------------+------+----------+-------+
1 row in set, 1 warning (0.007 sec)
```

Comment: "Is there a way to check what was killed by the max_statement_time" -- check for errors _and warnings_ after the statement.  (It won't be in any "log".)

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that v1..v4 are literal constants (numeric, string, date, etc), and assuming you really mean `=` in all 4 cases, then

```
INDEX(col1, col2, col3, col4)
```

(in any order) is optimal for that one `SELECT`.  This will also minimize I/O *for that query*.

There are many reasons for "high" I/O.  I'll cover a few of them.

- Data is bigger than the cache, the size of which is controlled by `innodb_buffer_pool_size`.  How big is the table?
- That setting should be configured to be about 70% of *available* RAM.  How much RAM do you have?
- If any items in the query are `TEXT` or `BLOB`, there *may* be extra I/O.
- Currently you do not have a good index, and it had to check 10859204 rows to find the 48 you needed.  With the index, above, only 49 rows need to be fetched.
- "Waiting for table metadata lock" -- This implies that you are doing some serious blocking or LOCKing or ALTERing.  What other queries are going on?
- Since the buffer_pool is shared among all MySQL processes, some other query *may* be at fault.
- Adding the index should eliminate the 48 vs 1765 puzzle and any need for max-query-time.
- You should use `ENGINE=InnoDB`; `MyISAM` has more locking/blocking issues.
- If you provide more specifics, I may have more tips.

(after your edit)

The "Rows" in `EXPLAIN` is an estimate; it can easily be off by a factor of 2 either way.

- `Rows_sent` in the slowlog is exact.

Comment: (I updated, based on your edit)